# Why can't I call pip with --target and --editable?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I'm using

> cd MyPackage
>
> pip install --target deploy_directory .

to prepare packages for deployment on Google App Engine, but for testing under dev_appserver.py, I would like to install the package in development mode (i.e., with '--editable').  However, when I try:

> cd MyPackage
>
> pip install --target deploy_directory --editable .

I get something like:

```
Complete output from command /my/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Path/To/MyPackage/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps --home=/var/folders/5h/k2xt_l014s1c1gvmnssm963c0000gp/T/tmpoml8u3:
/my/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:364: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.1.0
' to '0.1.0'
  normalized_version,
usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: -c --help-commands
   or: -c cmd --help

error: option --home not recognized
```

Which seems to happen because 'setup.py develop' doesn't accept '--home'.

Here's my setup.py:

```
 from setuptools import setup, find_packages
 import os
 import sys
 from codecs import open

  setup(name="MyModule",
        version="0.1.0",
        long_description="Blah blah",
        author="Me",
        packages = find_packages()
  )
```

How can I easily work on code that running under the development server?

Comment: How does your `setup.py` look?

Comment: same here. "pip install -e ." works but if I add the -t option I get the same error. Any workarounds? Can I just copy the relevant folders?

Answer (score 3):

This is known to be broken since a long time. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3246 and https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/562.

In the second link it is mentioned that some developers covered their use case with replacing `--target` by `--src`. I have not tried this myself though.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802628/17169563), the `--target` and `--editable` options don't get along very nicely.

A workaround to this was mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4390#issuecomment-773775693) and it involves to first create a wheel and then install from that wheel.

Here's a one-liner that worked for me

```
path_to_package=<path to package> && install_location=<install location> && whl_name=$(pip wheel --editable $path_to_package | grep -o "filename=.* size=") && pip install --target $install_location ${whl_name:9:-6}
```

and just change `<path to package>` and `<install location>` to what you want them to be.